# Why does overflow-x: hidden make my absolutely positioned element become hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out, why setting **overflow-x: hidden** to container makes my element with **position: absolute** hidden.

The effect is better understood in this demo.
https://codepen.io/Karina1703/pen/LYMzqEj

Here is the code:

```css
.container {
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* If I remove this line everything is how I expect it to be! */
}


.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 160px;
}


.button {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}


.menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
    top: 20px; 
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <button class="button">Button</button>
      <nav class="menu">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: that's what `overflow: hidden` is for –  what do you expect? An absolutely positioned element doesn't take any space inside its relative parent, and if it's moved outside the parent's borders, it becomes invisible when `overflow: hidden` is applied to the parent.

Comment: if it doesn't take up space inside the element, why does the overflow-x-hidden property apply at all?

Comment: Because the height  of the element whose position is set relative is not specified, hence, anything beyond the button's (which is the only element which has a height set by default) height will be hidden. If you set a sufficient height for the .box matching it's content height; that content will be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because currently your `div.container` has the width and height equal to the only relative element within it (which is the button). Since the navigation it's positioned absolutely under the button it's not visible.

In order to understand the statement above we need to start by understanding how `position: absolute` works. When an element position is absolute it's removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. The element is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor (if any) or to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values)

With this in mind, we can now ensure that the height of the `div.container` and `div.box` have always enough height to show the inner elements.

[Here](https://codepen.io/giuliogallerini/pen/XWoeOZg) is the codepen where the solution can be visualised.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <style>
        .container {
            width: 100vh;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow-x: hidden;  /* If I remove this line everything is how I expect it to be! */
        }


        .box {
            position: relative;
            width: 160px;
            height: 100%;
        }


        .button {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
        }


        .menu {
            position: absolute;
            width: 160px;
            top: 20px; 
            width: 100%;
            background-color: green;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
          <button class="button">Button</button>
          <nav class="menu">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why div.container has 0px height? because it contains a button with some height

Comment: Indeed, it does have the height of the button since it's relatively positioned by default. However the `div.menu` it's below the button making it invisible, this can be seen in the linked codepen. 

I will edit my answer to reflect this comment.

Answer (score 1):

With `position: absolute` you tell that `.menu` will not take place, so its size on the parent container is 0. As of [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)

> If overflow-x is hidden, scroll, or auto and the overflow-y property is visible (default), the value will be implicitly computed as auto.

Y-size is computed from the `container`'s elements excluding absolutely positioned elements but absolutely positioned elements will be visible only inside this container. Try adding `top:4px;left:10px;` to your `.menu` CSS and it will appear.